# How to install XML module

Tags: xml, ubuntu, php-7

I'm working with Ubuntu 17.04 and PHP 7.0 and I've got a problem when I try to install xml module.

If I try to install the xml module with this command ...

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

I've got this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 php7.0-xml : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.18-0ubuntu0.17.04.1) 
but 7.0.18-1+deb.sury.org~yakkety+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And If I try to install php7.0-common I've got this message:

```
php7.0-common is already in its most recent version 
(7.0.18-1+deb.sury.org~yakkety+1).
```

So, how can I install the xml module?

Comment: What happens if you do sudo apt-get -f install? Also, I think this is more of a server fault question. You might have better luck there.

Comment: If I do sudo apt-get -f install nothing happens :( This is the last message that I receive: 0 updates, 0 new ones will be installed, 0 to remove and 7 not updated.

Comment: I'd add this ppa then apt-update, apt-get -f install, apt-upgrade and try to install again. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: It works to me!!! Thank you soooooooooo much!!!!